# Can an Assassin use Assassinate with ranged spell attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, assassin

From the PHB (page 97):

> **Assassinate**
>
> Starting at 3rd level, you are at your deadliest when you
> get the drop on your enemies. You have advantage on attack rolls
> against any creature that hasn’t taken a turn in the combat yet. In
> addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a
> critical hit.

Can this feature be used also with ranged spell attacks, such as *Eldritch Blast*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assassinate gives you advantage on attack rolls. So if a spell requires you to make an attack roll than yes, Assassinate can be used in conjunction with that spell.

If it was only meant to be used with weapon attacks than it would specifically say so.

Comment: But remember that sneak attack doesn't work with spells, so a bow attack is likely going to do far more damage for a rogue.